# Compare Strings read from txt file in java

Tags: java, string, file, compare

I read a string from a txt file and I want compare this string with my reference. But it displays "not ok" and I don't know why.

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("nh.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            int numCharsRead;
            //char[] charArray1 = new char[1024];
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            while ((numCharsRead = fileReader.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }



            String resultat = new String(charArray);
            String resultat1 = resultat.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            System.out.println(resultat1);
            String a="Nihao";
            if(a.equals(resultat1)){System.out.println("ok");}
            else System.out.println("not ok");


            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can't see your input file, but perhaps you're reading a carriage return ?

Comment: What is the value fo `resultat1`?

Comment: can you provide the txt file

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi i hava Ni hao in my txt file

Comment: @npinti the value for resultat1 is Nihao

Answer (score 1):

This is because the string `resultat1` is a 1024 char length, its [possible to a java string to have `\0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815849/2037229), its in memory like this (if the file contains `Niaho`):

```
Nihao\0\0\0..
```

And because `\0` is not a [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), this will not make any change:

```
resultat.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

So you need to replace this char `\0` with nothing:

```
resultat.replaceAll("\0", "");
```

or simply compare the reference string `a` to `stringBuffer.toString()` which is `numCharsRead` length:

```
if(a.equals(stringBuffer.toString())){System.out.println("ok");}
            else System.out.println("not ok");
```