# Can some ASCII characters interrupt/end any string/array/stream in Java?

Tags: java, string, char, compression, ascii

I'm currently working on a little program that compresses text by replacing repeated words/phrases with a reference to the next occurrence - thus compressing a string into a shorter string with no metadata or arrays or whatever techniques are used in real compression. My references are stored as pairs of chars in a sense like this:

```
(char)7 + (char)(length << 4 + offset)
```

where `(char)7` is just an arbitrary selected char for signaling a compressed reference. Both length and offset are full range `byte` variables referring to the number of words that will be substituted and the offset until the next occurrence. *(I'ts not relevant for the question, but I'm treating them as unsigned bytes by manual unsigned<->signed conversion.)*

```
//Example compression would result like this:
String input = "compression and compression";
String output = (char)7 + (char)18 + " and compression"
//(char)18 - binary 0001 0010 would be saying 1 word repeat, from 2 words ahead.
```

**TL;DR:**, I'm afraid that there may be special situations that can interpret my custom char as a special ASCII character. I am aware that Strings in java ignores `\0` characters ([Due to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815755/end-of-string-character-in-java)). But are there any other java methods/classes that could cause problems? Say if I were to send/convert the compressed string with things like streams, buffers, readers, char arrays and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` holds Unicode symbols, called **code points**, and `char` has 2 bytes and is in UTF-16, a special format. Especially there are *surrogate pairs* of 2 chars to represent code points above the 2 byte range, above 2<sup>16</sup>.

Alternatively to using `char` you could do all in code points, which in java are of type `int`. However there is an upper limit to legal Unicode.

You could however get away with your encoding, as long as you do no conversion to bytes in some encoding. And *that* is the real problem.

As there is no clean solution, `byte[]`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `ByteBuffer` (with putShort and such) might be cleaner.

Comment: Do you mean that I should strictly avoid converting my compressed string into bytes? Would I be better off never making the output into a string and rather make a byte[] directly for the compressed data?

Comment: Yes, in that way you can have short offsets (one byte), long offsets (two bytes) and such. Also using indices in the bytes array. Should look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

There are no values that have any special meaning of "interrupting" or "ending" a Java string, array or stream.

(At least, not unless you have designed your application, or used / chosen a protocol or encoding that places a special meaning of that nature on specific values.  I don't imagine that you have done ... because if you had done, you would not be asking this question.)

Comment: I see! No I haven't made my own protocol/encoder, but I just started learning about network programming, and I don't know things like how another computer would interpret an incoming stream of bytes, or how it would convert that stream back into a string.